# Django, running code later/re rendering after page is opened , when token is acquired

Tags: python, django, django-forms, token

I'm building an application in Django that uses a form that needs to gather some data from an API the token to authenticate with this API is gathered by using a login flow. However when the token expires Django refuses to run, so refreshing the token by re-authenticating becomes impossible.

Is their a way to run the code from the form after the login has happened so that Django does not try to run it on start-up. Or re-render the form when the page is opened/refreshed

However this form requires some data from the that API. To access this API I need to use a token, this token is obtained by going to the login flow in the beginning of the application, which then stores the token for use within the application. However when the Token expires Django won't start. So it's impossible to go true the sign-in flow to obtain a new token.

I'm using the Microsoft graph API and requesting data from the AzureAD.

I've tried to place the part of the form in a Try: Except:

This works however it doesn't reload with the correct information on refreshing or reopening the page containing the form.

The form:

```
    sign_in()
    infile = open('token.pickle', 'rb')
    token = pickle.load(infile)
    infile.close()
    depDict = get_deps(token)
    depDict = [(v, k) for k, v in depDict.items()]
except:
    pass



class userCreationForm(forms.Form):
    firstName = forms.CharField(label='First name', max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-controll', 'type': 'text', 'placeholder': 'First Name'}))
    lastName = forms.CharField(label='Last name', max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-controll', 'type': 'text', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label='email', max_length=100, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-controll','type': 'email', 'placeholder': 'Email adress'}))
    try:
        department = forms.CharField(label='department', widget=forms.Select(choices=depDict, attrs={'class': 'form-controll'}))
    except:
        department =forms.CharField(label='department', widget=forms.Select(choices=[('DEP-Everyone','DEP-Everyone')], attrs={'class': 'form-controll'}))
```

The view:

```
    user_create_form = userCreationForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = user_create_form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            messages.info(request, 'User will be created')
            form = user_create_form()
            # first_name = user_create_form.firstName
            # last_name = user_create_form.lastName
            # UPN = user_create_form.email
            # password = "test123!"



    else:
        form = userCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'user_creation_page.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: move the creation of the `department` field into the form's `__init__()` method. Right now it's at the class level and when the form is imported (when Django launches), the class is already created, including running your API call. If you move it to `__init__`, it'll run each time the form is instantiated.

Comment: Hi, I've done this it looks like the following now:  `def __init__(self):
        try:
            department = forms.CharField(label='department', widget=forms.Select(choices=depDict, attrs={'class': 'form-controll'}))
        except:
            department = forms.CharField(label='department', widget=forms.Select(choices=[('DEP-Everyone','DEP-Everyone')], attrs={'class': 'form-controll'}))` how ever now non of the fields render. The page does.

Comment: when you create the field in the form's init method, you can't just create a variable `department` as it will be lost after you exit the init method.

Comment: `self.fields['department'] = ...` is how you add the field "department" to the form. Also make sure you create `depDict` inside the init as well (or make it callable, i.e. a function that returns the dict) so that it's run each time the form is created. That's the whole point of this.

Comment: I've made the request to the depDict a function that gets called. And made the syntax change. However It's still not rendering anything and I'm quite at a loss. I don't really understand how to tell the rest of the Django app where department field is located because the `init` method doesn't return anything. It looks like this now `self.fields['department'] = forms.CharField(label='department', widget=forms.Select(choices=get_depDict(), attrs={'class': 'form-controll'}))
`

Comment: are you also calling `super().__init__`? Please learn a bit of python object oriented programming when using django. this is just standard subclassing.